# node js childprocess python geojson as paramater

Tags: python, node.js, json, geojson, child-process

I am doing an sql query on my postgis database in node.js which returns a GEOJSON object. I want to pass that GEJSON (as a string) to a python child process on the same server:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn('python', ['scripts/hello.py', JSON.stringify(geoJson)]);
```

but I am getting this error in node:

```
Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG
       ...
```

I noticed that with a smaller GEOJSON obect there is no problem.

My next solution would be to write the GEOJSON object into a file from node.js and only pass the path to the childprocess but i wonder if there is a better solution without using that temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

What about pass the data via stdio stream?

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn('python', ['scripts/hello.py']);
process.stdin.end(JSON.stringify(geoJson));
```

Comment: having some trouble to get this running.. Do you have a minimal example with a python script?

Comment: precisely im getting this error: events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EOF
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:792:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
    at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:40:7)
    at Socket._destroy (net.js:618:3)
    at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:794:10)